# Error establishing a database connection - Multi-site with subsite don't exisit

Tags: multisite, database, errors

I have a multi site setup to which I have placed

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.example.com' );
```

In the wp-config.php file

However when I visit a site which dose not exist (e.g. http://nosite.example.com) I'm greeted with the following

> Error establishing a database connection

Instead of being redirected to the homepage as defined.

I have disabled all plugins and reverted back to the default .httaccess however this has not solved the issue.

How can I solve this and have a none existing subsites redirected to the appropriate location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by

replacing

```
 define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
```

with

```
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you find your issue, but I believe that you should not have set up your multisite with www

[Before_You_Create_A_Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network) States

> While it's not recommended to use www in your domain URL, if you chose
>   to do so and plan to use subdomains for multisite, make sure that both
>   the site address and the WordPress address are the same. Also keep in
>   mind some hosts will default to showing this sort of URL: nosite.www.example.com